# Django date field enable/ highlight only certain dates

Tags: django, datefield

My files are as below :

*Forms.py*

```
class FilterDaywiseNew(forms.Form):
    search_Day = forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),required=True,initial=datetime.date.today)
```

*Views.py*

```
def DayWiseFilterPage(request):
    form = FilterDaywiseNew()
    return render(request, 'agelist.html',{'form': form})
```

*agelist.html*

```
<form method="post" action="SearchDisplay" id="searchFilterForm">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mb-0">
            {{ form.search_Day|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My rendered html is like this

```
<div id="div_id_search_Day" class="form-group">

<label for="id_search_Day" class=" requiredField">
    Search day<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
</label>
```

I have a bunch of dates, that I would want to populate the datefield with, so that only these dates are enabled/ highlighted/ can be selected, like this

[image: Calendar With Certain Dates Enabled]

Solutions given use JQuery to do this. I dont want to use JQuery. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Thanks,

Comment: Why dont you want to use JQuery? it's very easy to implement.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working directly, hence. It doesnt enter the function given below. Independent HTML seems to be working fine, but when put into Django project, it fails.
 $("#id_search_Day").datepicker({
....
})